# ctrl+z doesn't send htop to the background

Tags: zsh, background-process, htop

I'm using zsh on macOS 12.4, apple M1.

When I run htop normally using the command `htop` and use `ctrl+z` it behaves as expected and sends the process to the background. I can evoke it again using the `fg` command and after that send it again to the background using `ctrl+z`

However, when I run htop and send it to the background directly using the command

```bash
htop &
```

and evoke it using `fg`, `ctrl+z` no longer sends it to the background. `ctrl+z` has no effect whatsoever.

Is this expected? I am not running into the same issue when I use `vim &`.

Comment: Which version of `htop` are you using? It works for me on Linux, but maybe it depends on the version. You can check with `htop -V`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can reproduce it on Ubuntu with `htop` and some other ncurses-based applications like `mutt`.

At the root of the issue is the fact that when zsh's line editor (zle) is active all the VQUIT, VSUSP, VDSUSP, VSWTCH, VLNEXT special characters in the tty device discipline are disabled, so that upon pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>, zle receives a `^Z` instead of the system trying to send a SIGTSTP to the foreground process group (VSUSP setting).

You can see it [there](https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh/blob/zsh-5.9/Src/Zle/zle_main.c#L265) in the code.

When zsh leaves the line editor and a command is run (or a job is put back in foreground), the terminal state is restored (including with SUSP restored as `^Z` if that's what it was before).

Now when you start `htop &` a TUI application, you reenter the line editor straight away (back to the prompt) while `htop` initialises in background.

`htop` and ncurses applications in general do the same kind of thing as zle does: they retrieve the initial tty settings, change them  to adapt to their own use and upon exit (or suspension) restore the saved tty settings.

Now the problem is that when started in background, the initial tty settings that the ncurses application retrieve are those are set by zle, not the regular one because by the time they initialise, you're already back at the prompt. So at that point they see SUSP disabled.

When they try to change the settings (which change other things than the SUSP setting), they're suspended with a SIGTTOU as they're not in foreground.

Then when you `fg` it, zsh does restore the tty settings to the regular one, before sending a SIGCONT to the application, but then the application just resume their `tcsetattr()` which apply their changes on top of the initial settings, so they're reapplying the disabling of SUSP.

If I run:

```
stty -a < /dev/pts/1
```

(where `/dev/pts/1` in my case is the tty `htop` is connected to and has been resumed)

I see:

```
intr = ^C; quit = <undef>; erase = ^?; kill = ^U; eof = ^D; eol = <undef>; eol2 = <undef>; swtch = <undef>; start = <undef>; stop = <undef>; susp = <undef>; rprnt = ^R; werase = ^W;
lnext = <undef>; discard = <undef>; min = 1; time = 0;
```

So it's not that `htop` is immune to SIGTSTP or that `htop` is not properly in foreground, it's that on that terminal, there's no character that causes SIGTSTP to be sent.

If I start `htop` as:

```
htop & sleep 1
```

Then, when `htop` retrieves the initial settings, you won't be back at the prompt as `sleep` will still be running, and you'll find that you can still suspend `htop` after resuming it with `^Z`.

You'll get the same behaviour with `tcsh` which also disables SUSP at its own line editor, but not bash and other shells that use readline, nor the few other shells I've tested which means they can't bind `^Z` in their own line editor. Some of them do disable some special settings. For instance bash disables LNEXT (usually `^V`).